# SQL Query formatting issues

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, sum, format, case

Struggling to figure out the correct formatting for my sql query.

```
SELECT
r.rental_id,
r.rental_date,
r.return_date,
r.inventory_id,
i.inventory_id,
i.film_id,
f.film_id,
f.rental_duration,
DATEDIFF(
    days,
    r.rental_date,
    r.return_date
) AS days_out,
SUM(CASE WHEN r.return_date = NULL) as 'Not_Returned',
SUM(CASE WHEN days_out > cc.rental_duration) as 'Returned_Late',
SUM(CASE WHEN days_out =< cc.rental_duration) as 'Returned on Time',
COUNT(r.rental_id) AS 'Total Rentals'
FROM rental AS r, inventory as i, film as f
WHERE r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id and i.film_id = f.film_id
```

I am trying to get the total number of rentals that are returned late or on time. Any help and tip would be greatly appreciated. My main question is how to properly format my sum case statements and when to use the SUM or COUNT operation.  The resultant table should have Returned on Time, Returned Late, Not Returned, and Total Rentals with only a single entry each.

Comment: Forget formatting.  Learn how to use `join`.  Don't sue single quotes for column aliases.

Comment: You would need to provide sample data and expected results. We can't guess from your query. Consider also adding a database tag to your question: sql-server, oracle, mysql...?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the case is confusing. Below is a straightforward example.

```
SELECT   ProductNumber, Name, "Price Range" =   
      CASE   
         WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale'  
         WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50'  
         WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'  
         WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'  
         ELSE 'Over $1000'  
      END  
FROM Production.Product
```

The SQL Server SUM() function is an aggregate function that calculates the sum of all or distinct values in an expression.

Knowing this, could you try to re-write your function.